# How to list disks, partitions and filesystems in Linux?

Tags: hard-disk, utilities, block-device

In Windows, if you type `LIST DISK` using DiskPart in a command prompt it lists all physical storage devices, plus their size, format, etc. What is the equivalent of this in Linux?

Comment: Physical storages, nothing logical like partitions?

Comment: A synology device I'm using will use df and parted -l, but not lsblk or fdisk -l.

Comment: A good reference: https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-disk-partitions/

Answer (score 289, accepted):

There are many tools for that, for example `fdisk -l` or `parted -l`, but probably the most handy is `lsblk` (aka *list block devices*):

#### Example

```
$ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN  RM  SIZE    RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0      0   238.5G  0   disk
├─sda1         8:1      0   200M    0   part  /boot/efi
├─sda2         8:2      0   500M    0   part  /boot
└─sda3         8:3      0   237.8G  0   part
├─fedora-root  253:0    0   50G     0   lvm   /
├─fedora-swap  253:1    0   2G      0   lvm   [SWAP]
└─fedora-home  253:2    0   185.9G  0   lvm
```

It has many additional options, for example to show filesystems, labels, etc. As always `man lsblk` is your friend.

Comment: Note: `-f` switch is very useful, try: `lsblk -f`

Comment: @Dor it is worth explaining what additional options do, if you are recommending their use. `-f` or `--fs` shows the information about filesystems, such as format, crypto, raid member, etc. It is somewhat slower than the default though.

Comment: fdisk -l and parted -l give me no output at all.

Comment: You'll like this : you can do `sudo lsblk --scsi`  and this shows the disk types including name(sda,sdb,..), scsi addr, type,vendor, model, rev, .. it's easy to find which is which when you want to physically locate the disk.

Comment: “As always man lsblk is your friend.” `-ash: man: not found`

Answer (score 37):

Another way to quickly see the filesystems is the command df.
On my machine (Finnish localization) it shows like this:

```
ptakala@athlon:/mnt$ df
Tiedostojärjestelmä 1K-lohkot      Käyt   Vapaana Käy% Liitospiste
/dev/root            38317204  19601752  16762352  54% /
devtmpfs              4063816         0   4063816   0% /dev
tmpfs                 4097592     81988   4015604   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 4097592     10120   4087472   1% /run
tmpfs                    5120         8      5112   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                 4097592         0   4097592   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9           535267140 287403688 220666804  57% /work
/dev/sda7           288239836 201635356  71956016  74% /home
tmpfs                  819520         4    819516   1% /run/user/113
tmpfs                  819520         8    819512   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1            39070048  37083304   1986744  95% /mnt/sda1
/dev/sda10           22662140  14032580   8629560  62% /mnt/sda10
/dev/sda5            29280176  20578032   8702144  71% /mnt/sda5
```

It won't show the file system type, but usually that is non-essential, and you see by one eyedrop everything needed.

human readable sizes:

```
ptakala@athlon:/mnt$ df -h
Tiedostojärjestelmä  Koko  Käyt Vapaa Käy% Liitospiste
/dev/root             37G   19G   16G  54% /
devtmpfs             3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                4,0G   89M  3,9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                4,0G  9,9M  3,9G   1% /run
tmpfs                5,0M  8,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                4,0G     0  4,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9            511G  275G  211G  57% /work
/dev/sda7            275G  193G   69G  74% /home
tmpfs                801M  4,0K  801M   1% /run/user/113
tmpfs                801M  8,0K  801M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1             38G   36G  1,9G  95% /mnt/sda1
/dev/sda10            22G   14G  8,3G  62% /mnt/sda10
/dev/sda5             28G   20G  8,3G  71% /mnt/sda5
```

Comment: This only shows mounted devices. `lsblk` would show all block devices.

Comment: df -h works on qnap devices

Answer (score 35):

The other answers don't show the UUID which is useful to use as reference in boot scripts and configs like `/etc/hdparm`. so here:

```
$ sudo lsblk --output NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,MODE
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL     UUID                                 MODE
sda                                                               brw-rw----
├─sda1      ntfs   WinHyperX 2D6BFC4E0CDCFAD8                     brw-rw----
├─sda2      ext4   HyperX    ef761208-bab3-4a26-87d2-ed21a7f5a1bb brw-rw----
└─sda3      swap             74259007-a80b-4866-b059-0bdbe6331040 brw-rw----
sdb                                                               brw-rw----
└─sdb1      ext4   4TB       91e32977-0656-45b8-bcf5-14acce39d9c2 brw-rw----
sr0                                                               brw-rw----
mmcblk0                                                           brw-rw----
└─mmcblk0p1 exfat            9C33-6BBC                            brw-rw----
```

Other available columns:  (see `lsblk --help`)

```
        NAME  device name
       KNAME  internal kernel device name
     MAJ:MIN  major:minor device number
      FSTYPE  filesystem type
  MOUNTPOINT  where the device is mounted
       LABEL  filesystem LABEL
        UUID  filesystem UUID
          RO  read-only device
          RM  removable device
       MODEL  device identifier
        SIZE  size of the device
       STATE  state of the device
       OWNER  user name
       GROUP  group name
        MODE  device node permissions
   ALIGNMENT  alignment offset
      MIN-IO  minimum I/O size
      OPT-IO  optimal I/O size
     PHY-SEC  physical sector size
     LOG-SEC  logical sector size
        ROTA  rotational device
       SCHED  I/O scheduler name
     RQ-SIZE  request queue size
        TYPE  device type
    DISC-ALN  discard alignment offset
   DISC-GRAN  discard granularity
    DISC-MAX  discard max bytes
   DISC-ZERO  discard zeroes data
```