# Is swap a partition, but not a file system?

Tags: ubuntu, swap

Is swap a partition, but not a file system? Is that the reason why `df` doesn't show it?

Is there a command which can list all the partitions (whether they hold file systems or not)?

Thanks.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           788M  1.5M  786M   1% /run
/dev/sda3       260G   17G  231G   7% /
tmpfs           3.9G  403M  3.5G  11% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       550G  323G  200G  62% /home
tmpfs           788M   56K  788M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           788M  4.0K  788M   1% /run/user/1001

$ cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda2                               partition   15625212    12653864    -2
```

Comment: Yes. `sfdisk -d /whatever/file/or/device`.

Comment: Also, you can use Gparted, a gret application pre-installed in meny Debian distributions.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks. I guess `sfdisk -l` is more appropriate

Comment: @mosvy that is a good answer. It is short, but such is the nature of this question. Please copy to an answer, so we can ✓ you.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I don't think this question hasn't been answered before.

Comment: `parted -l` seems also can do the same

Comment: `lsblk`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157154/80886

Comment: you may want to check out **kernel.org** and the somewhat *official* description of SWAP, specifically **swap management** and **describing the swap area**   https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is swap a partition, but not a file system?

The common way to set up a swap space is indeed to use a partition (like your `/dev/sda2`). The swap space has some identifiers, so it can be identified as such, but it's not a file system: it doesn't contain files.

You could of course also put swap space on a file on some regular filesystem.

<sub>(I wouldn't say swap *is* a partition, but in can lie *on* a partition.)</sub>

> Is that the reason why df doesn't show it?

That, and the fact that `df` only shows *mounted filesystems* (visible to the process).

> Is there a command which can list all the partitions (whether they hold file systems or not)?

All disk partitioning tools; `fdisk`, `sfdisk`, GParted, what have you. They might or might not show what's inside the partitions though.
(`/proc/partitions` also contains a list, but not much details.)

Answer (score 3):

> Is swap a partition, but not a file system?

A swap File / Partition is just a big [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) where the kernel stores Randomly Accessible Memory.  Although RAM can contain files, it needs a RAM DISK conversion to do that.

> Is that the reason why `df` doesn't show it?

Yes, from the `man page`:

> NAME
>         df - report file system disk space usage

> Is there a command which can list all the partitions (whether they hold file systems or not)?

```
parted --list
```