# lsblk doesn't show size on some partitions

Tags: lsblk

(Ubuntu 20.04)

`lsblk -f` shows:

```
NAME        FSTYPE     LABEL             UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
---
nvme0n1                                                                                      
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs       Recovery          A6F8B146F8B11611                                    
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                         B6B1-83C2                              62,5M    34% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3                                                                                  
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs                         EA9CC7CA9CC7900D                       77,9G    60% /media/az/EA9CC7CA9CC7900D
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs                         8EFE5BB7FE5B9675                                    
├─nvme0n1p6 ext4                         30c2e908-17b9-47a2-b68a-5a0df3f62f8e  513,5G    23% /
└─nvme0n1p7 swap                         7c366bb0-c008-4285-8a67-1acae6e25d2d                [SWAP]
```

It doesn't show the size for some of these partitions, e.g. `nvme0n1p1`, `nvme0n1p3`, `nvme0n1p5`, `nvme0n1p7`. Maybe because it couldn't extract that information.

But getting the absolute size of the partition should always work.

So I tried `lsblk --output NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,FSSIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT`:

```
NAME        FSTYPE     LABEL             UUID                                 FSSIZE FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme0n1                                                                                             
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs       Recovery          A6F8B146F8B11611                                           
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                         B6B1-83C2                               95M   62,5M    34% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3                                                                                         
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs                         EA9CC7CA9CC7900D                     194,3G   77,9G    60% /media/az/EA9CC7CA9CC7900D
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs                         8EFE5BB7FE5B9675                                           
├─nvme0n1p6 ext4                         30c2e908-17b9-47a2-b68a-5a0df3f62f8e   714G  513,5G    23% /
└─nvme0n1p7 swap                         7c366bb0-c008-4285-8a67-1acae6e25d2d                       [SWAP]
```

But it still does not show that. Why? How can I make `lsblk` show this information?

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` in comparison gets the information:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4B824D75-DA39-42FF-815F-87DF7ADB2401

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     923647     921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2     923648    1126399     202752    99M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1126400    1159167      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4    1159168  408538890  407379723 194,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5  408539136  409597951    1058816   517M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6  409597952 1933035519 1523437568 726,4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1933035520 1948659711   15624192   7,5G Linux swap
```

(Btw, related questions, as I was searching for a nice tool to print information about all my disks: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157154/how-to-list-disks-partitions-and-filesystems-in-linux), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/how-do-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-in-the-system))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out: `FSSIZE` was the wrong flag. I needed just `SIZE` instead.

`lsblk --output NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,SIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT` gives:

```
NAME        FSTYPE     LABEL             UUID                                   SIZE FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme0n1                                                                       931,5G                
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs       Recovery          A6F8B146F8B11611                       450M                
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                         B6B1-83C2                               99M   62,5M    34% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3                                                                      16M                
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs                         EA9CC7CA9CC7900D                     194,3G   77,9G    60% /media/az/EA9CC7CA9CC7900D
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs                         8EFE5BB7FE5B9675                       517M                
├─nvme0n1p6 ext4                         30c2e908-17b9-47a2-b68a-5a0df3f62f8e 726,4G  513,5G    23% /
└─nvme0n1p7 swap                         7c366bb0-c008-4285-8a67-1acae6e25d2d   7,5G                [SWAP]
```